# How did the Klingons Wage a War with Cardassia?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In Deep Space 9, there was an ongoing plotline involving a war between Cardassia and The Klingon Empire. Obviously the did have the war, but the crux of my question is how they managed to do so without having the support of The Federation. Most maps I've seen of the Star Trek universe, such as [this one (Federation and Vicinity)](http://sttff.antspad.net/AST_MAP.html), show at least a good portion of Federation space separating the Klingons and the Cardassians. Without Federation support how did the Klingons establish a supply line without also making war with the Federation?

Comment: Space isn't flat like that map.

Comment: Like mu said http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwoDSpace?from=Main.Two-DSpace

Comment: It would be nice if better DS9 friendly maps came out.  I think Cardassian space has to be on top or bottom of Romulan and Federation space in 3D and have a border near enough to klingon space to justify an invasion.  Which is impossible using early TNG maps that was supposed to be exploring the frontier on the other side of the Federation away from classic TOS nemesis powers and meeting new ones like Cardassians and Ferengi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**They don't seem to share a common border.** Despite the warlike posture of both races and the potential for conflict between them, the sole incident (dismissed by Garak as 
a "minor skirmish", albeit a bloody one that lasted 20+ years) was over a single Nebula located *inside* Federation space, something that seems vanishingly unlikely if they had any common contact.

In [The Way of the Warrior](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/474.txt), we see a Klingon task force making preparations to invade Cardassian space. In order to reach the Federation Cardassian border, **they need to pass through Federation space.**

Since the Federation and Klingons are allies (courtesy of the Khitomer Accords), presumably the Klingons can freely pass through Federation space to wherever they need to go, up to and including the Cardassian border.

> **SISKO :** *Welcome to Deep Space Nine, General. Is there something I can do for you?*
>
> **MARTOK :** *It has been a long journey. My men require shore leave.*

Comment: After the Klingons withdraw from the Khitomer Accords, their attitude about crossing Federation space is probably something akin to "Try and stop us."

Comment: @Omegacron - Note that Sisko was staggered to see them decloak.

Comment: The gist I got from it was that the Klingons were cloaked as they passed through (or near) Federation space. As Omegacron says, they were surprised to see the Klingons show up at DS9.

Comment: @Valorum- do you remember what that 'minor skirmish' was called, I'm having trouble recalling it.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Betreka_Nebula_Incident